# Error while using nativescript-drop-down plugin

Tags: nativescript, dropdown, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to create login page in Nativescript using Angular. I need to add dropdown in my login page. So I decided to use [nativescript-drop-down](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-drop-down/) for my requirement.

Following versions are installed on my PC:-

- Nativescript Version - 7.0.10
- NodeJS Version - 10.16.0

I run following command to install "nativescript-drop-down" in my nativescript project

> npm i --save nativescript-drop-down

Here is my code:-

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "@nativescript/angular";
import { DropDownModule } from "nativescript-drop-down/angular"
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        DropDownModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,        
        LoginComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**login.component.html**

```
<StackLayout>
    <DropDown #dd backroundColor="red" itemsTextAlignment="center"
     [items]="items"                  
     row="0" colSpan="2"></DropDown>
</StackLayout>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent{
     public items: Array<string>;
     constructor() { 
        this.items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.items.push("data item " + i);
        }
     }
}
```

While doing this I am getting below error:-

> ERROR in node_modules/nativescript-drop-down/angular/index.d.ts:17:22
>
> - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (nativescript-drop-down/angular)
> which declares DropDownModule has not been processed correctly by
> ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version
> of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking
> with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be
> compatible with Ivy.
>
> 17 export declare class DropDownModule {

Please help me in resolving error.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No. I didnt find any. I changed my approach now. If you are looking to use dropdown then you need to subscribe here :- https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-drop-down